# How to remove time from date format?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble working on this kata from code wars. The goal of the kata is to remove the time from the date format (I'll have the instructions listed below). The method I'm using is index splicing to remove everything after the comma (this is where the time is located). I am coding this in Python version 3.8.

[Instructions](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56b0ff16d4aa33e5bb00008e/train/python):

> You're re-designing a blog and the blog's posts have the following
> format for showing the date and time a post was made:
>
> Weekday Month Day, time e.g., Friday May 2, 7pm
>
> You're running out of screen real estate, and on some pages you want
> to display a shorter format, Weekday Month Day that omits the time.
>
> Write a function, `shortenToDate`, that takes the Website date/time in
> its original string format, and returns the shortened format.
>
> Assume `shortenToDate`'s input will always be a string, e.g. "Friday
> May 2, 7pm". Assume `shortenToDate`'s output will be the shortened
> string, e.g., "Friday May 2".

Code:

```
def shorten_to_date(long_date):
    #your code here
    new_date = long_date[:-5]
    
    print(new_date)
```

Comment: In this case, you can easily split the string by.... comma.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the strings have the same length, so it better to just split by the comma and return the first string

```
new_date = long_date.split(',')[0]
```

If you really need to use index, you can find the index of the comma in each string and use it to slice it

```
def shorten_to_date(long_date):
    index = long_date.index(',')
    return long_date[:index]
```

Comment: I completely forgot that function. I was too invested in trying to splice and use indexes to accomplish my goals.

Comment: @DevineSims I added a generic solution with index, but the first one is simpler.

Comment: I agree with that.  I'll be sure to add these to my notes. My skills are rusty so I'm using code wars to catch up on what I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

I made the problem harder than it seems, one of the main problems was that I kept calling print instead of returning the function. Another error was that I wanted to use index instead of just using `rsplit()` to just remove everything after the comma.

```
def shorten_to_date(long_date):
    #This line of code will remove all text after the comma is added
    return long_date.rsplit(',')[0]
```